# How to decrypt encrypted String in C# but encrypted in java (jasypt)

Tags: java, c#, jasypt

i need to decrypt the encrypted string in MsSQl. the encrypted String is encrypted using jasypt as i have the source code (java)

my problem is, i cannot decrypt back the encrypted string in C#.

**this is the code used in java:**

```
public String encrypt(String strClearText){
    String strKey="password";
    StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
        encryptor.setPassword(strKey);
        String encrypted= encryptor.encrypt(strClearText);

        return encrypted;
    }
```

I try to convert the jasypt.jar to dll using **ikvm** and still no luck. 
Is there any way i can do to overcome this problem? so that the encrypted password can be use in java and also in c#?

i cannot change the method of encryption as this encrypted String is being used by many other software. i hope you guys can tell me/teach me another way to overcome this problem..

Thank you :)

Comment: [here](https://github.com/jboss-fuse/jasypt/blob/master/jasypt/src/main/java/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java#L979) is a sources of `decrypt()` method that actually decrypt `byte[]` - maybe you can rewrite it

Comment: @vasily.sib - this one is to decrypt at java side?

Comment: yes, this is Java code

Comment: @vasily.sib - to decrypt in java, i am able to do that. The problem is, im using C# to decrypt it back. :(

Comment: as I said before - _"maybe you can **rewrite** it"_

Comment: @vasily.sib - oh my bad. Thank you for the information. :). Currently im still trying to fit the code in the C#.

Comment: Since no parameters are specified, the default parameters are used: For the algorithm this means `PBEWithMD5AndDES` (at least for the current version Jasypt 1.9.3 and also 1.9.2). The return value consists of an 8-byte salt followed by the ciphertext. The IV is not included, because it is determined by the `MD5` hash algorithm like the key. A C#-implementation of `PBEWithMD5AndDES` can be found [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16450/Emulating-PBEWithMD5AndDES-Encryption-under-NET). Only the decryptor has to be added analogous to the already implemented encryptor.